# Wildfly Unable to inject value?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, wildfly, wildfly-8

I am attempting to get a private, closed source jar to work on a wildfly server.

Here is the stack trace I'm getting:

```
2016-03-03 15:57:20,909 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.ra.deployer."eclsconnector.rar": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.ra.deployer."eclsconnector.rar": JBAS010446: Failed to start RA deployment [eclsconnector.rar]
    at org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.deployment.ResourceAdapterDeploymentService$1.run(ResourceAdapterDeploymentService.java:157)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.DeployException: IJ020060: Unable to inject: com.empolis.ecls.server.j2ee.jca.impl.ECLSManagedConnectionFactory property: ECLSPropFile value: /app/CMS/modules/server/config/properties/ecls.prop.jboss
    at org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.createObjectsAndInjectValue(AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.java:2038) [ironjacamar-deployers-common-1.1.5.Final.jar:1.1.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.createObjectsAndInjectValue(AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.java:1173) [ironjacamar-deployers-common-1.1.5.Final.jar:1.1.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.deployment.ResourceAdapterDeploymentService$AS7RaDeployer.doDeploy(ResourceAdapterDeploymentService.java:209)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.deployment.ResourceAdapterDeploymentService.start(ResourceAdapterDeploymentService.java:118)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
```

What does this exception mean? What files should I look in and what should I look for to attempt to fix it? Is it necessary that I decompile something, modify it, and recompile, or does this indicate that I've configured something incorrectly on Wildfly?

Sorry for the scarce details. If you let me know which files would be useful for assisting me, I can provide those. This is just a large project and the first time I've worked with wildfly so I don't know where to start looking.

Comment: It looks like it can't inject the property `ECLSPropFile` with the value `/app/CMS/modules/server/config/properties/ecls.prop.jboss` into the `ManagedConnectionFactory`. My guess would be there is no field named `ECLSPropFile` or method named `setECLSPropFile(String)`.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins - I decompiled `ManagedConnectionFactory` and am able to see it does have a `setECLSPropFile(String)` method. I also set up Byteman and inserted log at enter and exit for the method. The at enter is triggered but at exit never is. I'm going to continue investigating... Possibly an exception is getting raised in the method and Byteman isn't able to intercept it?

Comment: Does the method attempt to do something like `new File(String)`? Maybe that's the issue since the file doesn't exist on the file system.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins - Not directly, no... but perhaps one of the methods it calls does do that.

Comment: If you're using Byteman you might be able to inject something here to print the stacktrace which would give you some more details. https://github.com/ironjacamar/ironjacamar/blob/ironjacamar-1.1.5.Final/deployers/src/main/java/org/jboss/jca/deployers/common/AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.java#L2032-L2041

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have this problem, what you should do is set up Byteman.

That entails downloading and installing it from here: http://byteman.jboss.org/ , then adding the following to your `java_opts`:

```
-javaagent:/path/to/byteman.jar=script:/path/to/bytemanRules.btm,boot:/path/to/byteman.jar,listener:true
```

Replace the two spots where it says `/path/to/byteman.jar` with the path to your  byteman jar and the one place where it says `/path/to/bytemanRules.btm` with the path to your actual rules file.

If you had a stack trace like mine, the place to start with byteman would be `ECLSManagedConnectionFactory.setECLSPropFile` - add rules around that so that it logs to a file when it enters, exits, or throws from that method. The next step would be to decompile that class.

Find the class file (jar/war/ear/rar files are all just zip files - easy to open), then decompile it. IntelliJ has a decompiler built in. Use the decompiled class to figure out what some methods it calls are. Back in byteman, add rules based on the methods you see that it calls (use `AT INVOKE` and `AFTER INVOKE`), to figure out where it's going and getting stuck.

One last trick that might be useful is adding `-verbose:class` to your `java_opts`. This causes Java to spit out the full path to each jar that it loads, along with the classes that it found in each jar.

Ultimately my problem above - completely impossible to determine from looking at this stack trace alone - was that I had different versions of a single class in different jars. Something that `ECLSManagedConnectionFactory.setECLSPropFile` was calling meant to talk to one copy of the class, but instead talked to another copy of the class... which lead to the issue.

I can't give more specific help, but hopefully this short list of tools and techniques gives you a useful starting place for debugging this issue and others with Wildfly (or even Java in general... nothing here is really specific to Wildfly.)